# Como se chama a omissão de um som vogal entre duas consoantes, típica de alguns falantes portugueses?

Tags: pronúncia

Em geral essa omissão transforma uma palavra polissílaba em trissílaba.

> - **"diferente"** sendo pronunciado como **"di-fren-te"**
> - **"competentes"** sendo pronunciado como **"comp-ten-tes"**

Comment: Acho que se trata aqui da [isocronia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isocronia_(lingu%C3%ADstica)) do português europeu. [“Uma das diferenças mais perceptíveis entre o português europeu o brasileiro é sua prosódia. O português europeu é uma língua de ritmo acentual, com as sílabas átonas de menor duração que as tônicas. **As vogais átonas sofrem redução frequente ou até mesmo cancelamento,** e há uma tolerância geral a consoantes em fim de sílaba.”](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

À eliminação de fonemas no interior de palavras (não necessariamente vogais) dá-se o nome de *síncope*.

Mas o apagamento da vogal [ɨ] (vogal que não ocorre no Brasil) não se dá exclusivamente entre duas consoantes. O apagamento dá-se mais frequentemente no início de uma palavra, como em ***e**star* e pode também dar-se imediatamente antes do fim de palavra, como em *sempr**e*** (ou *diferent**e***). [Este artigo de Sara Candeias e outros](http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/til/stil2011_English/jdp/artigos/STIL2011_JDP_P5.pdf) tem uma análise da frequência do apagamento nestas várias situações (includindo separadamente os casos em que a vogal se encontra numa sílaba aberta ou fechada) e também em função do contexto fonético à esquerda e à direita.

Comment: Agora que mencionaste essas outras diferenças, dou-me conta que sempre as ouvi mas nunca reparei nelas.  Principalmente o "sempr-".  Ah, uma pergunta: qual vogal não ocorre no Brasil?

Comment: @Centaurus A vogal [ɨ] (e mudo).

Comment: @Centaurus, vê aqui o som: http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/